# Why is python trying to open files with <string> in the name?

Tags: python, python-module, strace

While debugging a problem with module loading, I've noticed something weird in the `strace` output for Python trying to load a non-existing module:

```
$ strace python3 -c 'import nosuchmodule'
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python37.zip/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.7/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module n"..., 52ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nosuchmodule'
```

Why does cpython try to open files with name `<string>`?

This happens both with Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu and Python 3.7.3 on Debian.

Comment: When I import a non-existent module from the interpreter it gives me something similar: `/home/td/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip/<stdin>`. stdin instead of string, is that progress?!

Comment: @tdelaney it's `<string>` when the source is passed as `-c` on the command line, and `<stdin>` when the source is read from stdin. It seems that python tries to re-read the source file to create a backtrace, and uses these dummies when the source doesn't come from a file.